# "Interesting tag" questions not highlighted in Chrome for SE sites

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stackexchange-2.0, tag-watching

When viewing a list of questions from the homepage, Questions page, or Unanswered page (and possibly others), the questions tagged with my interesting tags are not highlighted in Chrome.  I have observed this both on boardgames.se and android.se.  Highlighting is still working fine in Firefox and on my Android phone's browser.

Highlighting does work as expected on SO, though, so the problem is not universal.

FWIW, I'm using Chrome 7.0.517.41 for Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: I did a little more digging into this.  According to an "inspect element", the css background color is applied correctly, it just isn't rendering properly.  I have found bugs in Chrome that render colors improperly, at least in Linux, so I wonder if this is a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the cache in your browser is a bit mixed up -- can you try hard refreshing with CTRL+F5?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is working for me on rpg.stackexchange.com

Chrome 7.0.517.41 for Mac